# Need help to do math with PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery/Javascript

```
<script>
                var Quantity;
$("select").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    var price = <?php echo $row[price];?>;
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
            });
    $(".plan_price").text("price : " + parseInt(str) * price + " baht");
    Quantity = parseInt(str);
}).change();
    </script>
```

and this for php/sql

```
if ($row[item_amount] - 1 == 0) {
                $sql = "update item set active='2',item_amount=item_amount-1,buy_time=NOW() where id='$id'";
            } else {
                $sql = "update item set item_amount=item_amount-1,buy_time=NOW() where id='$id'";
            }
```

I want to know if there is any way for me to subtract/add the value of the javascript variable Quantity to/from the $row[item_amount] in php as I need the Quantity to be subtracted from the database.

Comment: _note:you can embbed javascript into php but you cant embbed php inside javascipt_

Comment: @Kaii What do you mean by that?

Comment: It simply means you can assign the php variable value to a javascript variable, but not the vice versa is possible.

Comment: You will have to Ajax to your server the changes on the client

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-code-in-my-javascript-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with $row[item_amount] through an ajax call. You cannot directly subtract `Quantity` to or from `$row[item_amount]`.

Comment: ohhh thats sounds difficult, any other suggestion to a different way of doing this or something :'( this is so hard haha :(